# スタック・オ－バーフローのサーバーについて

Tags: 討議

現在、日本の複数サイトで接続し難い、あるいは出来ないといった事象が確認されています。
原因としてはDoS攻撃が考えられます。
出典：『http://d.hatena.ne.jp/Kango/20160901/1472746600』

以前スタック・オ－バーフローもそのような攻撃でダウンしたことが『http://jp.techcrunch.com/2014/02/17/20140216stackoverflow-goes-down-programmers-around-the-world-panic-its-back-up-now/』の記事になっていますが、これに関してどう思いますか。